# This is a question about elementary number theory.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The integers $220$, $251$, $304$ represent three consecutive perfect squares in base $b$. Determine the value of $b$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $3b+1$ and $b^2-5b+3$ are two consecutive odd integers, hence $b^2-8b+2=2$, so the only possibility is $b=8$, and it fits.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use the identity, $$(a+2)^2+a^2-2(a+1)^2=2$$

Here $(a+2)^2=(304)_b=3b^2+4$ and so on

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the differences between three consecutive squares are two consecutive odd integers.

> The first difference is $31$ so the second will be $33$ which means that $25+3=30$ and $b=8$